# Resharper reformatting Linq statement to put into and select on same line

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

When I type in a Linq query style statement like

```
var stuff = from x in things
            group x by x.Something into g
            select g;
```

Resharper is reformatting it to

```
var stuff = from x in things
            group x by x.Something
            into g select g;
```

And then complains about it because it breaks the StyleCop rule SA1103.  Is this a bug in Resharper or is there some combination of settings that I need to change to keep it from doing this reformatting?

**Edit**

JetBrains has confirmed that this is a bug and it is fixed in version 8.0.

Comment: I've filled a ticket with JetBrains and will update when I hear back from them.

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to the ticket and marking answer on this question to close it off?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The "request" I submitted doesn't seem to be public.

Comment: Here's a link to the issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-338644

Comment: Chuckled when I saw the priority was a show-stopped, wish I could let stuff like that stop me from releasing code :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the options for ReSharper, there is a single option under Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other called "Align Multiline Constructs, LINQ query".

This appears to control the relevant formatting (disabling it causes the multi-line linq query to not align by position, but simply by tab indentation).

Based on the fact that there isn't any more granular control over what happens with `into`, I'd say it's either a bug or a missed requirement on their part. Perhaps raise a ticket.

To be honest I was expecting to find something under "Line Breaks and Wrapping", but nothing was in there for linq queries.

<sub>ReSharper 7.1.1000.900 on VS 2012</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I tried turning that option off, but it still put the into and select on the same line.  It just doesn't line them up with the from.  Guess this is a bug.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I was expecting to find something under "Line Breaks and Wrapping", but alas nothing. I'd suggest that if they enhance ReSharper to cater for this that a configuration option should be placed in there.